# Sharing Bookdown book without publicizing

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm working on a data analysis project in R, where I'm doing some logistic and multilevel modeling with sensitive, private data in R. I have fallen for the **bookdown** package in R, and I have created a fairly extensive book about our workflow and analysis pipeline. The thing is - I'm hosting this book locally on my computer, which means I have no real way to share this book with my team. In the past, I have created .html files with R Markdown or Jupyter, which then I could email or store in the cloud for others to open. Is there a way I can create a **bookdown** book that is shareable some other way than public URL access? Thanks--

Comment: Have you see the [bookdown output formats](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/output-formats.html)? You can make, HTML, PDF, ebook, etc.

Comment: That documentation has been super helpful. I was outputting to an HTML file, but saw that bookdown knits an HTML file for every chapter/section of the book. I was hoping for a single file for the whole book, but it appears I need to share the whole directory of HTML files in order for someone to see all the contents of the book. Unlike a PDF or Ebook, which **is** just one file.

Answer (score 1):

I am also writing internal books for my organization. I think what I would do is to place the html file in the share drive so that only people with the share drive access can access your book.

Comment: Great to hear someone else is doing the same. Do you share the entire folder of HTML files generated by bookdown? Or do you have a single file you place in the share drive?

Comment: I would share all of them in a folder and ask people to start with the index file and the whole book will be rendered in the browser

Comment: What about sharing with people that don't have direct access to a shared folder directory? With Google Drive, for example, you need to download all of the files locally before opening because it just renders a preview when you try to open index.html. Surely there is a better way.